# How do I properly curry fn.apply with null?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, apply, built-in

Background: I want to map an array of arrays of parameters over a pure fn that takes multiple parameters. I thought currying apply with null and calling `Array.map()` would work.

```
[[x1, y1], [x2, y2], [x3, y3], ... [xn, yn]].map(curry(fn.apply, null))



var curry = function(fn, value) {
    return function (x, y) {
        return fn(value, x, y);
    };
}
var fn = (x,y) => [x, y];
var fn_c = curry(fn.apply, null)
fn_c([1,2]);


Uncaught TypeError: Function.prototype.apply was called on undefined, which is a undefined and not a function
at <anonymous>:3:20
at <anonymous>:8:5
```

Only the `apply` gets remembered in the curried function, without the `fn` from which apply should stem. Thus the curried function tries to run `apply(x,y)` instead of `fn.apply(x,y)`, which fails of course.

How can I retrieve the apply-ed function to pass around?

Comment: Your functon "curry" does partial application, not currying. And it only works for functions with exactly three parameters.

Comment: Why not simply do `.map(arr => fn(...arr))`?

Comment: @Bergi can't use `...` (yep... IE support)

Comment: @Bergi Learned something new: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218025/what-is-the-difference-between-currying-and-partial-application#comment87580_218055

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  I forgot that functions are objects as well:

```
var curry = function(fn, value) {
    return function (x, y) {
        return fn(value, x, y);
    };
}
var fn = (x,y) => [x, y];
var fn_c = curry(Function.prototype.apply.bind(fn), null)
fn_c([1,2]);
```

... that's ugly. I'll just `.map(params => fn.apply(null, params))`.