# Javascript/ Typescript .bind() get Variable in bound function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, typescript, validation, mongoose

i want to bind a variable to a callback function, but mongoose already embeds a parameter named val into that function. When i want to bind another value with .bind() to the callback function I lose the original val attribute. Is there a way i can keep the original parameter and add my variable with .bind() to it?
Below is an example.

```
// gets val parameter from validator
const maxLengthValidator = (val: string): boolean => {
  if (val.length > 255) return false;
  return true;
};

const userSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    // unique: true
    validate: [
      {
        validator: maxLengthValidator, // includes a val attribute from post request
        msg: 'too short'
      },
    ]
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

export default model('User', userSchema);
```

What i want to do:

```
// gets val parameter from validator
const maxLengthValidator = (val: string, boundary: number): boolean => {
  if (val.length > boundary) return false;
  return true;
};

...
validate: [
  {
    validator: maxLengthValidator.bind(this, 255), // doesn't work, would need to specify the string for the val parameter
    msg: 'too short'
  },
]
...
```

So i can set a max length in the validator object.

Comment: Why not just do `validator: (val: string): boolean => maxLengthValidator(val, 255)`?

Comment: Alternatively, you could swap the order of parameters for `maxLengthValidator` and use your existing bind call. Or use currying like `const maxLengthValidator = (boundary: number): (string) => boolean => (val: string): boolean => {` and `validator: maxLengthValidator(255)`

Comment: Sometimes you just don't see the obvious :D thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Curry

You can change your function, so instead of taking two argument, it takes one, then returns a second function that takes the second argument. This is known technique is known as [curry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying).

```js
// maxLengthValidator :: number -> string -> boolean 
const maxLengthValidator = (boundary: number) => (val: string) : boolean  => {
  if (val.length > boundary) return false;
  return true;
};

// ... later ...

  validator: maxLengthValidator(255);
```

This way you can create different validators by invoking the function: `maxLengthValidator(10)` will give you a validator for 10 characters you can use. Since it's a function, you can just assign it to a variable, too:

```js
//userNameLengthValidator :: string -> boolean
const userNameLengthValidator: (val: string) => boolean = maxLengthValidator(10);
```

## Swap parameters to accommodate partial allocation

Instead of taking value *then* max length, take the length first. Same thing that currying the function did but instead this one can still take two parameters:

```js
const maxLengthValidator = (boundary: number, val: string): boolean => {
  if (val.length > boundary) return false;
  return true;
};

// ... later ...

  validator: maxLengthValidator.bind(this, 255);
```

Same basic idea. This time you have a bit more flexibility, though - you can call the function with both parameters `maxLengthValidator(10, username)` or just partially apply it with one. The latter produces pretty much the same thing as currying, since you still get a new function with the same signature:

```js
//userNameLengthValidator :: string -> boolean
const userNameLengthValidator: (val: string) => boolean = maxLengthValidator.bind(this, 10);
```

Despite the similarities [currying is not partial application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218025/what-is-the-difference-between-currying-and-partial-application). Also, it's possible to curry a function of any arity (any amount of parameters) to be able to take either one or many at a time. For an example, you can see [`_.curry`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#curry) in Lodash

```js
function add4(a, b, c, d) {
  console.log(a + b + c + d);
}

const curryAdd4 = _.curry(add4); 

curryAdd4(1)(2)(3)(4);
curryAdd4(1, 2, 3, 4);
curryAdd4(1)(2, 3)(4);
curryAdd4(1, 2, 3)(4);
curryAdd4(1)(2, 3, 4);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

## Partially apply with a placeholder or from the right

You can leave the signature as is, and just change your partial application. `Function#bind` is not very flexible but you can write your own or (better yet) use a library. I'll use Lodash again, since it has a good implementation for these:

### Partial application with a placeholder

Allows you to *skip* some of the parameters when partially applying. So you can skip the first one and just set the second:

```js
const maxLengthValidator = (val, boundary) => {
  if (val.length > boundary) return false;
  return true;
};

//userNameLengthValidator :: string -> boolean
const usernameLengthValidator = _.partial(maxLengthValidator, _, 10);

console.log(usernameLengthValidator("usernameTooLong"));
console.log(usernameLengthValidator("user"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

### Partially apply from the right

Partially apply starting from right to left, so it will first set `boundary`:

```js
const maxLengthValidator = (val, boundary) => {
  if (val.length > boundary) return false;
  return true;
};

//userNameLengthValidator :: string -> boolean
const usernameLengthValidator = _.partialRight(maxLengthValidator, 10);

console.log(usernameLengthValidator("usernameTooLong"));
console.log(usernameLengthValidator("user"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you! never heard of this technique before, helped me out a lot!