# Javascript function is not working properly

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to assign this function to this variable but no matter what i try nothing works and it gives me this error `TypeError: addSix is not a function`

```
 const createBase = num => {
      num + 6
    }
    
    let addSix = createBase(6);
    addSix(10); // returns 16
    addSix(21); // returns 27
```

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first; `num => { num + 6 }`. If you're using curlies, you have to add the return statement. Otherwise, lose the curlies: `num => num + 6`. This will implicitly add a return statement.

Then,
If you're not used to working with closures, I advice you not to use arrow functions.

And while this may work

```
const createBase = (num) => (num) => num + 6;
let addSix = createBase(6);
console.log(addSix(10));
console.log(addSix(21));
```

It's far more clear what it does for javascript beginners when you type it out like this;

```
const createBase = function(num) {
   return function (num) {
     return num + 6;
   }
};
let addSix = createBase(6);
console.log(addSix(10));
console.log(addSix(21));
```

What you had was the following, which if written out, makes it clear `addSix` was assigned the value of num+6 instead of being a function.

```
const createBase = function (num) {
    return num + 6
};
```

Answer (score 4):

For `addSize` to be a function, the return value of `createBase` must be a function.

`createBase` doesn't return **anything**. It has no return statement. Consequently, it returns `undefined`.

It doesn't even create a function to return.

Comment: I added return statement but still got the same error

Comment: @Roffybc — I'm guessing you put the return statement at the start of the only line in the function: So now you are returning a number. A number isn't a function.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of different problems:

1. `createBase` is a function that doesn't return anything.
2. The part that you're trying to create as a function (`num => { num + 6 }`) should either not have `{}` or should have a `return` ([more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45754957/why-doesnt-my-arrow-function-return-a-value)).
3. You're hardcoding the `6`, but you should be using the parameter value passed to `createBase`.

You need to make `createBase` a function that returns a function:

```js
// `createdBase`   vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
const createBase = num1 => num2 => num1 + num2;
// The func it returns     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

let addSix = createBase(6);
console.log(addSix(10)); // returns 16
console.log(addSix(21)); // returns 27
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues:

**Issue 1:**

You need to use a return statement or remove the curly brackets:

`const createBase = num => num + 6;`

**Issue 2:**

`createBase(6)` returns a number not a function.

Therefore you can't pass arguments to a number.

---

**Example:**

```
const createBase = num => num + 6;
let addSix = createBase(6); // this is a number, not a function
addSix(21); // you can't call a number with arguments as function and hence the error
```

`addSix` is a number, you can't pass arguments to it and use it as a function because it is not.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to create a single argument fucntion that returns a single argument function, which could be achieved like this.

```
const createBase = base => (num) => base + num;
let addSix = createBase(6);
addSix(10); // returns 16
addSix(21); // returns 27
```

Also see:

- Partial application
- Currying

(They're not quite the same: [What is the difference between currying and partial application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218025/what-is-the-difference-between-currying-and-partial-application))