# Is it possible to write an expression macro in Swift to curry any function?

Tags: swift, macros, currying

Let's say I would have this function:

```swift
enum HttpMethod: String { case get, post, put, patch, delete }

func makeRequest(
    method: HttpMethod,
    baseURL: URL,
    pathSegments: [CustomStringConvertible] = [],
    headers: [String:String] = [:],
) -> Response {}  // body is not important
```

What I would like, if it were possible, is to have an expression macro called `#curry` that does something like this:

```swift
// Every underscore signifies that that parameter
// should still be fillable in the newly generated function
let makeRequestToMyApi = #curry(makeRequest(
    method: _,
    baseURL: "https://example.com/api",
    pathSegments: _,
    headers: _,
))

let me = makeRequestToMyApi(
    method: .get,
    pathSegments: ["users", "me"],
    headers: ["Authorization": "Bearer blabla"],
)
```

And if a parameter that has a default value defined in the function definition (e.g. `headers`), is **not** given an underscore during the currying, then it should be assumed that that parameter should just be filled with its default parameter. And therefor no longer available to get filled later. Like so, for example:

```swift
let makeRequestToMyApi = #curry(makeRequest(
    method: _,
    baseURL: "https://example.com/api",
    pathSegments: _,
    // notice that headers is missing here,
    // since it was not marked with an _,
    // it will be assigned its default value
))

let me = makeRequestToMyApi(
    method: .get,
    pathSegments: ["users", "me"],

    // This would cause an error, because headers is not available to fill,
    // because headers was already assigned its default value of [:]
    headers: ["Authorization": "Bearer blabla"],
)
```

Is it possible to write an expression macro that does exactly this?

Comment: This is an interesting question that I'll have to toy around with when I have some time. I expect the answer is no because of the named parameters. If it's yes, be aware of the combinatorial explosion of functions that will be created. It's worth noting that this is not currying. It's partial application, so I'd probably call the macro `#partial` or maybe `#autopartial` (bleh?) rather than `#curry`. But this doesn't have  big impact on your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218025/what-is-the-difference-between-currying-and-partial-application

Comment: Actually, I think the named parameter are ok, because there is no actual currying, so there are no function types required. Yes, this may be possible with a macro (though it'll still have the combinatorial problem if there are many parameters). I'll play around with it later if no one beats me to it (I expect someone will beat me to it because it's interesting).

Comment: @RobNapier Why is there no function types required? `makeRequestToMyApi` would surely be of a function type, right? You surely can't generate a new type with `callAsFunction` in an expression macro. Or are you thinking about working around this with a *declaration* macro?

Comment: @sweeper Yeah; I came to the same conclusion over lunch. The `let makeRequestToMyApi = #curry(...)` syntax is definitely impossible in Swift. I've been considering (just like you) whether a declaration macro will fix this, but.... meh? It's not feeling great. This is a really interesting puzzle, but I suspect there's nothing really practical here. I encourage all the regular #swift suspects to provide answers here because it may be entertaining even if not actually useful.

Comment: So are you guys saying that an expression macro can't return a newly generated function? That would be too bad indeed.

Comment: Would it make a difference if instead of using underscores we basically turn the thing into a closure? Like let add2 = #partial { add($0, 2)}. And yes I agree that partial is a better word in this case than curry.

Comment: The `#partial` in your `#partial {add($0, 2)}` isn't doing anything. It's equivalent to just the closure itself. The important point here is that macros can't do anything but generate code you could have written yourself. So try to write what you want by hand. When that works, you can automate the writing of it using a macro.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to make a macro for this because it's not possible to write it by hand. Consider a simpler function:

```
func f(x: Int, y: String) -> String { "\(x)\(y)" }
```

I want to partially apply `x`, leaving a function `(y: String) -> String`:

```
func f(x: Int) -> ((y: String) -> String) { { y in f(x: x, y: y) } }
```

With this, I could call:

```
let fx = f(x: 1)
fx(y: "one")
```

But that's not valid Swift. It'll give two errors:

```
Function types cannot have argument labels; use '_' before 'y'
```

And then:

```
Extraneous argument label 'y:' in call
```

Swift does not support argument labels in function types.

```
var f: (Int) -> String    // This is allowed
var g: (x: Int) -> String // This is not
```

So there is no kind of expression macro that can build this. There's nothing it can expand to.

I've been thinking a lot about how this might be written as a declaration macro, but even if it is possible (I'm still exploring), it's not going to be in the spirit of your example. It might be possible to have a macro that works like this:

```
// This particular syntax is probably impossible, but as an idea
#partial("makeRequestToMyApi", makeRequest, baseURL: "https://example.com/api")
```

And that might expand to, in the best of possible worlds:

```
func makeRequestToMyApi(method: HttpMethod,
    pathSegments: [CustomStringConvertible] = [],
    headers: [String:String] = [:],
) -> Response {
    makeRequest(method: method, 
                baseURL: "https://example.com/api", 
                pathSegments: pathSegments,
                headers: headers)
}
```

But even if that's possible, you'll notice that it declares a function. That means it has to be done at compile time, so `"https://example.com/api"` has to be a string literal in your source code.

I don't think anything more dynamic than that can exist. Again, not because of macros but because of the syntax of closures. You just can't have named parameters in them, which blows up your goal.

It might be possible to construct an expression macro that returns a closure that takes a tuple of the rest of the parameters, but that would be pretty bad for Swift. And in your specific example would break the default parameters. It might be interesting to try to build (and I'm continuing to mess around with it), but I can't see how it would be useful.

---

After some more messing around, I'm even more convinced this is impossible, and that the "why" is important.

Consider this code:

```
func f(x: Int, y: String) -> String { "\(x): \(y)" }

// Partially apply x=1 to f
func fx(y: String) -> String {
    f(x: 1, y: y)
}
```

Now try to get to the following macro syntax to generate `fx`:

```
#partial("fx", "f(x: 1, y: _)")
```

A lot of this is surprisingly possible. I've gotten this far (code at the end):

```
func \(raw: name)(y: String) -> String {
    \(raw: fn.calledExpression)(\(raw: passedArguments))
}
```

I'm sure with a few more minutes, I could get the `y:` in the signature. That's not hard.

But then we come to the complete roadblock. The `String` type for `y` and the return type `-> String`. These aren't expressed anywhere in the code calling the macro, so they're not possible to generate.

At macro expansion time, there's no context about other functions that exist. So there's no way to know the type of `f`. There's no way to interrogate its signature. It may not even be known at this point. It's all just tokens. I don't think it's possible to get much further, and I don't see that changing since this is a pretty big part of how Swift macros work.

Anyway, here's the code that gets this far. It is terrible code. I was just working out if it's possible, not writing code you should emulate.

```
// THIS IS TERRIBLE CODE. IT'S JUST TO SHOW WHAT CAN BE DONE
@freestanding(declaration, names: arbitrary)
public macro partial(_ name: String, _ fn: String) = #externalMacro(module: "PartialMacros", type: "PartialMacro")

public struct PartialMacro: DeclarationMacro {
    public static func expansion(
        of node: some SwiftSyntax.FreestandingMacroExpansionSyntax,
        in context: some SwiftSyntaxMacros.MacroExpansionContext
    ) throws -> [DeclSyntax] {

        guard let name = node.argumentList.first?.expression.as(StringLiteralExprSyntax.self)?.representedLiteralValue,
                let call = node.argumentList.dropFirst().first?.expression.as(StringLiteralExprSyntax.self)?.representedLiteralValue
        else { fatalError() }

        let syntax = Parser.parse(source: call)
        guard let fn = syntax.statements.first?.as(CodeBlockItemSyntax.self)?
            .item.as(FunctionCallExprSyntax.self) else { fatalError() }

        let passedArguments = LabeledExprListSyntax(
            fn.arguments.map {
                guard $0.expression.is(DiscardAssignmentExprSyntax.self) else { return $0 }
                return $0.with(\.expression, ExprSyntax(stringLiteral: $0.label!.text))
            })

        
        return [
            """
            func \(raw: name)(y: String) -> String {
                \(raw: fn.calledExpression)(\(raw: passedArguments))
            }
            """
        ]
    }
}
```

That said, this is just the extent of what is possible with a freestanding macro. I believe this is solvable with an attached macro, but it's even more useless for this purpose. You have to declare it as part of the function's definition. For example:

```
@partial("fx", x: 1)
func f(x: Int, y: String) -> String { "\(x): \(y)" }
...
print("fx = \(fx(y: "abc"))")
```

I believe this (or something like it) is possible, but it's definitely not what you want.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for putting in all this effort. It's a pity that this doesn't seem to be possible. In Swift 1 or 2 you could write a function like `func f(x: Int)(y: String) -> String { return "\(x): \(y)" }. But they took it out since it wasn't used very often and it was apparently complex to compile. The reason I was hoping this macro could do the job is because I think that it could lead to some pretty awesome function pipelines / compositions / etc... But, too bad. I don't understand though why this isn't a built-in feature in most programming languages. It seems so useful to me.